# Error with web.config and CDATA

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, database-connection

I am getting the following error when I run my code:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'The configuration section cannot contain a CDATA or text element'

The application builds just fine but when I select the link to go to the view "about" in the application it throws the error above.

This is the line that it highlights in the code:

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CountryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

and this is the connection string in the web.config file:

```
 <add name="CountryConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=TestData" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
```

If more is needed let me know and I can post whatever you need

Here is the entire web config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application,   please     visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"       type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral"     publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"   type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="CountryConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=TestData" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  /> 
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: There's probably another error in your config file. If so, it produces an error the first time it is accessed. BTW: CountryConnectionSrting contains a typo.

Comment: Ok I fixed the typo and it still throws the error (I felt rather foolish posting a typo to begin with)

Comment: Can you post more of you config file? at least the complete connectionstrings section?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long I had another emergency pop up but I put the full web.config

Comment: There's a character in there that looks like a space but isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short solution: remove al whitespace between tags.

If I copy your config contains a character that renders as whitespace but actually isn't. To the config parser anything other than spaces and tabs, is text. Text is not allowed in config files.

```
// the spacing character
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new[] { ' ' })[0] // yields 194
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new[] { ' ' })[1] // yields 160

// the actual space
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(new[] { ' ' })[0] // yields 32
```

Try to change the config to:

```
 <connectionStrings><add name="CountryConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=TestData" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  /></connectionStrings>
```

Before re-adding spaces and enters

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CountryConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=TestData" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: That was perfect.  Now to just figure out why that was in there to begin with :-)